# make_signed<unsigned long>::type is int?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, types

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and the following code confused me a bit:

```
#include<type_traits>
auto x = std::make_signed<unsigned long>::type();
```

x will be of type int, but I would have expected long. I know that int and long in VS10 are both 4-byte integers. But even if a signed long fits into an int, int for me is not the signed integer type corresponding to unsigned long. So my question: is this a bug/technical inaccuracy or do the specifications of the standard allow this result?

Comment: I get `long` on GCC 4.9.0, FWIW.

Comment: On my VS2013 Express I also get `long`.

Comment: With VS2012, also a `long`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++11 20.9.7.3 [meta.trans.sign] describes `make_signed`:

> If `T` names a (possibly cv-qualified) signed integer type (3.9.1) then the
>   member typedef `type` shall name the type `T`; otherwise, **if `T` names a
>   (possibly cv-qualified) unsigned integer type then `type` shall name the
>   corresponding signed integer type, with the same cv-qualifiers as `T`** [*emphasis added*];
>   otherwise, `type` shall name the signed integer type with smallest
>   rank (4.13) for which `sizeof(T) == sizeof(type)`, with the same
>   cv-qualifiers as `T`.
>
> *Requires:* `T` shall be a (possibly cv-qualified) integral type or enumeration but not a `bool` type.

I would consider "the corresponding signed integer type" of `unsigned long` to be `long`. I don't think there's much room for interpretation.

EDIT: There's *no* room for interpretation since the standard defines "corresponding signed integer type". 3.9.1/2 states:

> There are five *standard signed integer types*: “`signed char`”, “`short int`”, “`int`”, “`long int`”, and “`long long int`”. ...

and 3.9.1/3:

> For each of the standard signed integer types, there exists a corresponding (but different) *standard unsigned integer type*: “`unsigned char`”, “`unsigned short int`”, “`unsigned int`”, “`unsigned long int`”, and “`unsigned long long int`”, each of which occupies the same amount of storage and has the same alignment requirements (3.11) as the corresponding signed integer type; that is, each signed integer type has the same object representation as its corresponding unsigned integer type. ...

The corresponding signed integer type of `unsigned long int` is clearly `long int`.

Comment: I agree, as does GCC.

Comment: Seems to be an unresolved issue of VS2010. As I mentioned in my comment above it's fixed at least in VS2013. If someone is willing to check VS2012 please leave a comment, as this still interest me.

Answer (score 0):

MAYBE your test might be flawed? I'm not sure as you posted no code.. However, for such a test, DO NOT use the size to determine what type is being returned. Such a test is inaccurate when a long can be same size as int.

For example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

std::make_signed<unsigned long>::type x;

int main()
{
    std::cout<<(sizeof(x) == sizeof(int));
}
```

is implementation defined and can return true if the long is the same size as the int. On most systems this will return true.

Doing:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

std::make_signed<unsigned long>::type x;

int main()
{
    std::cout<<typeid(x).name();
}
```

will print `L` if `x` is a `long` and it will print `I` if `x` is an `int`.

Comment: I didn't used the size to determine the type. As I mentioned in the question in VS2010 int and long are both 4-byte integers anyway see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It was the Visual Studio IDE that told me it's an int and since it's a header-only implementation I could also check the code. Changed the example a bit to make it more obvious.